# How can I continuously check semantic error with rust-analyser instead of upon saving only?

Tags: eglot, flymake, rust

I'm using `eglot` with `flymake` and `rust-analyzer`.

However, it seems to only check errors when I save the file:

[image]

`d()` is a non-existing function. It doesn't show any error, until I save the file:

[image]

Ideally it should continuously checks errors and report them in as soon as possible. Is there a way to configure it this way?

I've set my `flymake-no-change-timeout`:

```
(setq flymake-no-changes-timeout 0.2)
```

But it doesn't make a difference.

It does shows errors correctly upon saving, so I assume `eglot` is connected to the language server.